# Why PHP include() doesn't work with Twilio?

Tags: php, twilio

I am developing a small program with [Twilio service in PHP](https://www.twilio.com/docs/php/install).
Here is my Twilio side code:

```
<?php
    header("content-type: text/xml");
    echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
?>
<Response>
<?php
$currrentDate = date('Y-m-d', time());
$current = file_get_contents("1.txt");
$current .= "Caller (".$_REQUEST['From'].")";
file_put_contents("1.txt", $current);
$current .= " at ".date("m/d/y G:i:s", time())."<br/>";
file_put_contents("1.txt", $current);
?>
</Response>
```

This works fine, but when I use include function it doesn't work. I put the php code into another php file called "test.php".

```
<?php
    header("content-type: text/xml");
    echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
?>
<Response>
<?php
include("test.php");
?>
</Response>
```

And here is my test.php file.

```
<?php
$currrentDate = date('Y-m-d', time());
$current = file_get_contents("1.txt");
$current .= "Caller (".$_REQUEST['From'].")";
file_put_contents("1.txt", $current);
$current .= " at ".date("m/d/y G:i:s", time())."<br/>";
file_put_contents("1.txt", $current);
?>
```

Could someone tell me why? Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain "doesn't work" in more detail? What did you expect to happen, and what actually happened? I wonder if there's some code you should supply that connects to Twilio - can you edit that all in? Just so you know, "doesn't work" questions here tend to get downvoted, since it's not a very useful description of the problem.

Comment: Hi, thx for your advice. Actually, when I call my twilio number, the caller ID will saved into a txt file. I done this already. But when I use include function to include exactly the same code it won't work.

Comment: Hmm, your second item of code outputs the `<Response>` tags to standard output (Apache output to the browser, I guess) but `file_put_contents` redirects the inner content to a dated file. So, as far as I can tell, your response will always be empty. Shouldn't `test.php` output the contents of `$current` directly to stdout?

Comment: (You used the "it won't work" phrase again - oops! It is a good rule of thumb to avoid that in all questions).

Answer (score 2):

You are sending the header and the xml definition twice..

Remove

```
<?php
    header("content-type: text/xml");
    echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
?>
<Response>
```

and

```
?>
</Response>
```

from test.php

Comment: I don't have header in my second file, just a few code about write into file stuff from the primary one

Comment: Your code sample has the header in both files.

Comment: I put my test.php file on. There is no header there.